# How is equalizer a limit?

Tags: category-theory

**Source**: *Categories for the Working Mathematician*, second edition by Saunders Mac Lane.

In the text, an *equalizer* is defined as follows:

> If $J=\downdownarrows$, a functor $F:\downdownarrows\to C$
> is a pair $f, g: b\to a$ of parallel arrows of $C$. A limit object $d$
> of $F$, when it exists, is called an *equalizer* of $f$ and $g$. The limit diagram is $d\overset{e}{\rightarrow}b\overset{f}{\underset{g}{\rightrightarrows}}a$, $fe=ge$ (the limit arrow $e$ amounts to a cone $a\leftarrow d\to b$). The limit arrow is often called the equalizer of $f$ and $g$; it's universal property reads: To any $h: c\to b$ with $fh=gh$ there is a unique $h': c\to d$ with $eh'=h$.

By definition, a *limit* for the functor F is a universal arrow from the diagonal functor $\Delta: C\to C^J$ to $F$; it consists of a limit object $d$ of $J=\downdownarrows$ and a natural transformation $v: \Delta d\to F$, where $v$ is universal among natural transformations $\tau:\Delta c\to F$ for objects $c$ of $C$.

**My Question**: : How exactly does **equalizer** fit the definition of a **limit** in any sensible way? Even the notations such as $fe, ge, eh'$ seem absurd to me since $e$ is supposed to be a cone and all the others are arrows. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that the data of a natural transformation $v: \Delta d\Rightarrow F$ is the same as a collection of maps $\{v_j: d \rightarrow F(j) \,\}_{j\in J}$ in $ \mathcal{C}$ satisfying naturality, i.e. for any $f: j \rightarrow j'$ in $ J$ one has $F(f)\circ v_j = v_{j'}$. This is called a *cone over* $F$.

Furthermore, as it is pointed out a functor $F: \downdownarrows \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ is the same as two morphisms $f,g:b \rightarrow a$ in $\mathcal{C}$. Therefore (a priori) a cone over $F$ (with cone object $d\rightarrow \mathcal{C}$) is a collection of two maps $e:d\rightarrow b$ and $e':d \rightarrow a$ such that $e' = f\circ e = g \circ e$ (naturality). In other words, a cone is an object $d$ with a map $e: d\rightarrow b$ such that $f\circ e = g \circ e$ ($f$ and $g$ equalize under $e$).

Finally, the universal property implies that for any other such pair $(c,h:c\rightarrow b)$ there is a unique morphism $h': c \rightarrow d$ such that $h = e \circ h'$.